# Trigger another repo in github actions

Tags: github, devops, github-actions, cicd

I have two private repositories and I want to trigger github actions in second repository via manual running workflow on first repository.
I'm trying to run manually workflow on different repository but when workflow is executing on first repository I'm receiving error on Trigger Workflow event:

```
{
  "message": "Unexpected inputs provided: [\"repository\", \"commit\", \"env\"]",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event"
}
```

The workflow file in first repository:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      repository:
        description: 'Name of triggered repo'
        required: true
        default: '123re'
        type: string
      commit:
        description: 'Short commit'
        required: true
        type: string
        default: 'e123'
      env:
        description: 'Environment'
        required: true
        type: choice
        options:
        - dev
        - staging
        - prod

jobs:
  ping-pong:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set outputs
        id: vars
        run: | 
          echo "sha_short=$(git rev-parse --short HEAD)" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      - name: Trigger Workflow
        if: ${{ (inputs.env) == 'dev' }}
        run: |
          curl -X POST \
          -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
          -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}" \
          -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
          https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo/actions/workflows/test-connection.yml/dispatches \
          -d '{"ref":"main","inputs":{"repository":"$REPO","commit":"$COMMIT","env":"$ENV"}}'
        env:
          ENV: ${{ inputs.env }}
          COMMIT: ${{ steps.vars.outputs.sha_short }}
          REPO: ${{ inputs.repository }}
```

**UPDATE**
Workflow file from second (that is triggered) repository:

```
name: Remote Dispatch Action Responder

on: [repository_dispatch, workflow_dispatch]

jobs:
  ping-pong:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Event Information
        run: |
          echo '${{ github.event.inputs.commit }}' && echo "Event '${{ github.event.inputs.env }}' received from '${{ github.event.inputs.repository }}'"
```

Comment: Could you add the second workflow implementation?

Comment: I've added the second workflow

Comment: Ok. I observe you're sending a dispatch event to the second workflow with 3 inputs (repository, commit and env), but the second workflow `workflow_dispatch` event isn't configured to receive those 3 inputs. You should have a similar configuration to the one in the first workflow to be able to receive the inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending a `dispatch` event to the second workflow with 3 inputs (repository, commit and env), but the second workflow `workflow_dispatch` event isn't configured to receive those 3 inputs.

You should have a similar configuration to the one in the first workflow to be able to receive the inputs.

Like this:

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      repository:
        description: 'Name of triggered repo'
        required: true
        default: '123re'
        type: string
      commit:
        description: 'Short commit'
        required: true
        type: string
        default: 'e123'
      env:
        description: 'Environment'
        required: true
        type: choice
        options:
        - dev
        - staging
        - prod
```